# jQuery Lazy load for animated scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I would like to use [Lazy load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) to my site, but there is a little problem: I scroll the content with JS (animate the content with X px ), so I don't use the scrollbars. Sadly, lazy load doesn't trigger in this case. Got any ideas how to make this?

My site scrolling horizontally, all content `div`-s float near each other and only the current one is visible, all other are on `display: none;`

Here is a not so pro pic of my site: I marked with black the visible area and with red, the moving parts.

[my site in pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok1kC.jpg)

Comment: Could you clarify how you currently scroll the content via JS? Why not animate the scroll position instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some hours I've decided to use JAIL for this. Not the best solution, but better than nothing since I'm dumb with AJAX [JAIL aka jQuery Asynchronous Image Loader](http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail)

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is hook into when the content slides, then add the images in or the whole content with AJAX if thats your aim. Plugins will usually focus on the majority of use cases, so Lazy load might not be good for you.

Comment: I'm not so good with AJAX, that is why I tried to find similar solution for this :(

Comment: Guess it will be a learning experience then. :) Always cherish a chance to learn something new. [jQuery's AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) functions are pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would just write my own simple lazy load script:

```
$(function(){
  $('img').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.data('origImg',$this.attr('src'))
    $this.removeAttr('src') // or set a placeholder img
  })
  var $window = $(window), $container = $('#sliding_content')
  window.lazyLoad = function () {
    $container.find('img:not([src])').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this), left = $this.offset().left
      if (!(left < 0) && !(left > $window.width()))
        $this.attr('src',$this.data('origImg'))
    })
  }
})
```

And then when the divs are animated, call `lazyLoad()`.
Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: I'm a bit lame with JS, so should I write something to `origImg`? Or anywhere else?

Comment: I edited my code above. Just replace `containerSelector` with the selector for the element that has the horizontial scrollbar.

Comment: It does nothing, the `img` tag lacks the `src` property and Firebug doesn't give any error...

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: OK, try it. I tested it. If it still doesn't work can you post the CSS for your horiz scrolling?

Comment: Atm it has fixed width:
`#sliding_content {
 width: 15000px;
 position: relative;
}`

The animating is made with JS. It scrolls to a `div` with ID

 `$('nav ul a').live('click', function(event){
  
  var place = $(this).attr("data-place");
   place = place * 1700;
 
  $("#sliding_content").animate(
   { right: place }, {
    duration: 800, 
    easing: 'easeOutBack'
   });
  event.preventDefault();
 });`

Comment: OK, thought you were doing the scrolling with CSS. Take a look.

Comment: Can you post a demo on jsfiddle.net? Then I can play with it until it works.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code. Also, you need to call lazyLoad() every time you animate the divs.

Comment: Not and still no any error message... As I see, the script doesn't run in the `$container.find('img:not([src])').each(function(){` function... I've tried some ideas but nothing ):

Comment: Tested this... just change `slidingContent` to `sliding_content`.\

Comment: Nice, its almost perfect but there is one problem: only works after second click (slide). Check my site, you will see what I mean if you click the menus randomly).

Comment: Actually, it loads everything after second click... /: